# Linear model: comparing predictive power of two different measurement methods

Tags: regression, linear-model, mixed-model

I'm interested in predicting `Y` and am studying different two measurement techniques `X1` and `X2`. It could be for instance that I want to predict the tastiness of a banana, either by measuring how long it has been lying on the table, or by measuring the number of brown spots on the banana.

I want to know which one of the measuring techniques is better, should I choose to perform only one.

I can create a linear model in R:

```
m1 = lm(Y ~ X1)
m2 = lm(Y ~ X2)
```

Now let's say `X1` is a superior predictor of banana tastiness than `X2`. When calculating the $R^2$ of the two models, the $R^2$ of model `m1` is clearly higher than model `m2`. Before writing a paper on how method `X1` is better than `X2`, I want to have some sort of indication that the difference is not by chance, possibly in the form of a p-value.

How would one go about this? How to do it when I'm using different brands of bananas and move to a Linear Mixed Effect model that incoporates banana brand as a random effect?

Comment: Could you clarify why you can't include both predictors in the model? In your case, `X1` and `X2` would probably be correlated, as the brown spots probably increase with increasing time lying on the table.

Comment: I'm interesting in testing whether X1 or X2 is the better measurement method. If including them both in one model can answer that question, there is no problem doing that. Obviously they are both correlated as they measure the same thing.

Comment: I would like to say: when trying to measure banana tastiness, measuring how long it's been lying on the table is a better way to determine this than counting the number of brown spots (p < 0.05).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Later**

One thing I want to add after hearing that you have linear mixed effect models: The $AIC, AIC_{c}$ and $BIC$ can still be used to compare the models. See [this paper](http://areaestadistica.uclm.es/events/ModelosMixtos.pdf), for example. From other similar questions on the site, it seems that [this paper](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/People/roger/pdf/mathpsy04.pdf) is crucial.

---

**Original answer**

What you basically want is to **compare two non-nested models.** Burnham and Anderson [Model selection and multimodel inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929738) discuss this and recommend using the $AIC$, $AIC_{c}$ or $BIC$ etc. as the traditional likelihood ratio test is only applicable in nested models. They explicitly state that the information-theoretic criteria such as the $AIC, AIC_{c}, BIC$ etc. are *not* tests and that the word "significant" should be *avoided* when reporting the results.

Based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8558/21054) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8519/21054) answers, I recommend these approaches:

1. Make a scatterplot matrix (SPLOM) of your dataset including smoothers: `pairs(Y~X1+X2, panel = panel.smooth, lwd = 2, cex = 1.5, col = "steelblue", pch=16)`. Check if the lines (the smoothers) are compatible with a linear relationship. [Refine the model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61226/21054) if necessary.
2. Compute the models `m1` and `m2`. Do some model checks (residuals etc.): `plot(m1)` and `plot(m2)`.
3. Compute the $AIC_{c}$ ($AIC$ corrected for small sample sizes) for both models and calculate the absolute difference between the two $AIC_{c}$s. The `R` [package `pscl`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/index.html) provides the function `AICc` for this: `abs(AICc(m1)-AICc(m2))`. If this absolute difference is smaller than 2, the two models are basically indistinguishable. Otherwise prefer the model with the *lower $AIC_{c}$*.
4. Compute likelihood ratio tests for non-nested models. The `R` [package `lmtest`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/index.html) has the functions `coxtest` (Cox test), `jtest` (Davidson-MacKinnon J test) and `encomptest` (encompassing test of Davidson & MacKinnon).

**Some thoughts:** If the two banana-measures are *really* measure the same thing, they both may be *equally suited* for prediction and there might not be a "best" model.

[This paper](http://www.rochester.edu/college/psc/clarke/450315.pdf) might also be helpful.

Here is an exmple in `R`:

```
#==============================================================================
# Generate correlated variables
#==============================================================================

set.seed(123)

R <- matrix(cbind(
  1   , 0.8 , 0.2,
  0.8 , 1   , 0.4,
  0.2 , 0.4 , 1),nrow=3) # correlation matrix
U <- t(chol(R))
nvars <- dim(U)[1]
numobs <- 500
set.seed(1)
random.normal <- matrix(rnorm(nvars*numobs,0,1), nrow=nvars, ncol=numobs);
X <- U %*% random.normal
newX <- t(X)
raw <- as.data.frame(newX)
names(raw) <- c("response","predictor1","predictor2")

#==============================================================================
# Check the graphic
#==============================================================================

par(bg="white", cex=1.2)
pairs(response~predictor1+predictor2, data=raw, panel = panel.smooth,
      lwd = 2, cex = 1.5, col = "steelblue", pch=16, las=1)
```

[image: SPLOM]

The smoothers confirm the linear relationships. This was intended, of course.

```
#==============================================================================
# Calculate the regression models and AICcs
#==============================================================================

library(pscl)

m1 <- lm(response~predictor1, data=raw)
m2 <- lm(response~predictor2, data=raw)

summary(m1)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.004332   0.027292  -0.159    0.874    
predictor1   0.820150   0.026677  30.743   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6102 on 498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6549,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6542 
F-statistic: 945.2 on 1 and 498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

summary(m2)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.01650    0.04567  -0.361    0.718    
predictor2   0.18282    0.04406   4.150 3.91e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.021 on 498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03342,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03148 
F-statistic: 17.22 on 1 and 498 DF,  p-value: 3.913e-05

AICc(m1)
[1] 928.9961

AICc(m2)
[1] 1443.994

abs(AICc(m1)-AICc(m2))
[1] 514.9977

#==============================================================================
# Calculate the Cox test and Davidson-MacKinnon J test
#==============================================================================

library(lmtest)

coxtest(m1, m2)

Cox test

Model 1: response ~ predictor1
Model 2: response ~ predictor2
                Estimate Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)    
fitted(M1) ~ M2   17.102     4.1890    4.0826 4.454e-05 ***
fitted(M2) ~ M1 -264.753     1.4368 -184.2652 < 2.2e-16 ***

jtest(m1, m2)

J test

Model 1: response ~ predictor1
Model 2: response ~ predictor2
                Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
M1 + fitted(M2)  -0.8298   0.151702  -5.470 7.143e-08 ***
M2 + fitted(M1)   1.0723   0.034271  31.288 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

The $AIC_{c}$ of the first model `m1` is clearly lower and the $R^{2}$ is much higher.

**Important:** In *linear* models of *equal complexity* and *Gaussian* error distribution, $R^2, AIC$ and $BIC$ should give the same answers (see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61505/why-the-r2-aic-and-bic-criteria-give-different-best-model-for-models-of-eq)). In *nonlinear* models, the use of $R^2$ for model performance (goodness of fit) and model selection should be *avoided:* see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/behavior-of-r2-in-non-linear-models/60449#60449) and [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2892436/pdf/1471-2210-10-6.pdf), for example.

Comment: This is a practical detailed answer explaining well what could be done. What would have been even more striking would have been an example in which scatter plots, $R^2$ and $AIC_c$ lead to _different_ answers.

Comment: @NickCox That would indeed be interesting! If the models are linear and of equal complexity, and the errors have a Gaussian distribution, $R^2, AIC$ and $BIC$ should give the same answers. The truth is that I don't know how to produce an example ad-hoc where scatterplots, $R^2$ and $AIC_{c}$ lead to different answers (maybe someone could help me?). Sorry.

Comment: You need not apologise; I see it as good news whenever different sensible methods imply the same conclusion!

Comment: Excellent. The Cox test is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, my models are linear-mixed-effect models fitted with the lme4 package, which are not directly supported by the `lmtest` package. Before I dive into the literature written about cox-like tests with LMEs, does anyone know a readily available R-package to do it?

Comment: @Rodin No, I don't know any `R` package that could do that. Maybe [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/comparing-mixed-effect-models-with-the-same-number-of-degrees-of-freedom) can give you further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good 19th century answer in risk of neglect here. To compare two different straight-line fits, plot the data and the fitted lines and think about what you see. It's quite likely that one model will be clearly better, and that need not mean higher $R^2$. For example, it is possible that a straight-line model is qualitatively wrong in one or other case. Even better, the data and fit may suggest a better model. If the two models appear about equally good or poor, that's another answer.

The banana example is presumably facetious here, but I would not expect straight-line fits to work well at all....

The inferential machinery wheeled out by others in answer is a thing of intellectual beauty, but sometimes you don't need a state-of-the-art sledgehammer to crack a nut. Sometimes it seems that anyone publishing that night is darker than day would always have some one asking "Have you tested that formally? What is your P-value?".

Comment: +1, good points. I have explicitly stated that one should *not* use significance testing when dealing with the $AIC$ and alike.

Comment: Always good to take a step back and remember this so +1 but I am wondering if this might in fact just be the odd case where this is not particularly useful. Is it really quite likely that one model will be clearly better than the other when the two tentative predictors are different *measures* of the same thing as opposed to substantively different variables? Leaving aside the bananas for a minute, think slightly different questionnaires or a ruler vs. a laser rangefinder. One measure has to be extremely deficient for non-linearity to show up in one case but not the other.

Comment: I agree, but I feel happy to extend my answer to residual plots, etc. More generally, any way to judge this could run into the same objection, e.g. significance tests _might_ fail to reject equal performance, $R^2$ _might_ be practically identical. Having published on comparison of different measurement methods with real data, I do assert that choice of method will usually find a best method, but if two methods appear about equally good, then that's the answer, not an insoluble problem leading to methodological anguish.

Comment: I agree that the best way is to clearly present the data and the fits by the models. This way the reader can decide for themselves whether to accept any statement about one being better or not. However, I'm afraid reviewers will demand a significance test, purely out of a knee-jerk reaction. Gaël's comment about night and day is not so far off.

Comment: That was me on night and day....

Answer (score 2):

Do a Cox test for non-nested models.

```
y <- rnorm( 10 )
x1 <- y + rnorm( 10 ) / 2
x2 <- y + rnorm( 10 )

lm1 <- lm( y ~ x1 )
lm2 <- lm( y ~ x2 )

library( lmtest )

coxtest( lm1, lm2 )
?coxtest
```

(you will find references to other test).

See also [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/test-equivalence-of-non-nested-models/8519#8519) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/testing-the-difference-in-aic-of-two-non-nested-models). In especially, consider using AIC/BIC.